# Trigger Confused Assignment from Set to ID

Tags: apex

Basically I'm trying to write an after insert trigger for `ContentVersion` the object.  Whenever a new record is created by user ID "0052o000008YA5WAAW", I want to then check `ContentDocumentLink` and see if the `ContentDocumentId` exists in `ContentDocumentLink` and if the `LinkedEntityID` starts with 'a3r' which is a custom object of mine.  Then taking that `LinkedEntityID` for example "a3r7T000000L4K7QAK".  That value could exist in a field called `Ironclad_Information__c` on the objects Account, Opportunity, or Quote.

Then create a new `ContentDocumentLink` with following parameters

```
ShareType='V'
Visiblity = 'All Users'
LinkedEntityId = Account, Opportunity, or Quote (However many object records you found matching "a3r7T000000L4K7QAK" in the field Ironclad_Information__c across the three objects in this example) 
ContentDocumentLink = the Trigger.new value of the ContentDocumentId present in ContentVersion
```

In my example I was just focusing on `Quote`, but ideally I would like to create for all objects.

So I corrected my illegal set assignment, by stringifying my Set to an ID.  But now I get

> 17:43:07:006 FATAL_ERROR System.QueryException: Implementation restriction: ContentDocumentLink requires a filter by a single Id on ContentDocumentId or LinkedEntityId using the equals operator or multiple Id's using the IN operator.

And I can't see why, I am doing an In statement in my SOQL

```
for (ContentDocumentLink cvlink: [
    SELECT Id, ContentDocumentId, LinkedEntityId 
    FROM ContentDocumentLink 
    WHERE ContentDocumentId IN:contentDocumentIdSet
])
```

The `contentDocumentIdSet` was set by my Trigger firing and iterating them into a set.  Why is it erroring on that?

```
trigger AutoCreateContentDocumentLinkQuote on ContentVersion (after insert) {
    Set<Id> contentDocumentIdSet = new Set<Id>();
    for(ContentVersion cv:trigger.new)
    {
        if(cv.ContentDocumentId != null && cv.CreatedById == '0052o000008YA5WAAW')
        {
            contentDocumentIdSet.add(cv.ContentDocumentId);
        }
    }
    
    Set<Id> CleanedDocList = new Set<Id>();
    
    //Checks if Record was Made by Legal
    for(ContentDocumentLink cvlink: [SELECT Id, ContentDocumentId, LinkedEntityId FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE ContentDocumentId IN:contentDocumentIdSet])
    {   String idtext = String.valueof(cvlink.Id);
     
        if(idtext.left(3) == 'a3r')
        {
            CleanedDocList.add(cvlink.ContentDocumentId);
            
        }
    }
    
    //Find Quote that Exists
    List<Quote> q1 = [Select Id from Quote where Ironclad_Information__c in: contentDocumentIdSet limit 1];
        
    //Insert ContentDocumentLink
    ContentDocumentLink cDocLink = new ContentDocumentLink();
    cDocLink.ContentDocumentId = String.valueof(CleanedDocList);
    cDocLink.LinkedEntityId = q1[0].Id;//Add Quote ID
    cDocLink.ShareType = 'V';  //V - Viewer permission. C - Collaborator permission. I - Inferred permission.
    cDocLink.Visibility = 'InternalUsers';//AllUsers, InternalUsers, SharedUsers
    Insert cDocLink;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If the set is empty, this will cause the exception you see here. Abort early if there are no Id values:

```
if(contentDocumentIdSet.isEmpty()) {
  return;
}
```

Also, this code won't work:

```
String idtext = String.valueof(cvlink.Id);
 
if(idtext.left(3) == 'a3r')
{
    CleanedDocList.add(cvlink.ContentDocumentId);
    
}
```

You're checking the Id field, so the type will always be a ContentDocumentLink Id, not anything else. By the way, you should avoid the key prefix check model. Do this instead:

```
if(cvlink.LinkedEntityId.getSObjectType() == MyCustomObject__c.sObjectType) {
```

It's a bit longer but provides compile-time safety. Also, key prefixes are case sensitive, but the `==` operator in Apex is case-insensitive, so you could end up matching `a3r` and `a3R`, which may be two different, legal prefixes in your org.